# Образец плагина спойлера для TinyMCE 4.x

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Решил поделиться с сообществом простеньким плагином для создания спойлера через редактор TinyMCE (версия редактора 4.3.3). С учетом не самой подробной документации и немногочисленных примеров, думаю, что он кому-нибудь будет полезен.

По ходу его создания были решены такие вопросы как: создание диалоговых окон, создание многострочных полей ввода, удаление html-элементов из окна редактора (в частности самого спойлера), определение элемента на котором стоит курсор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот полезные ссылки, которые могут пригодиться при создании плагина.

1. [Официальная документация](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/)
2. [Типы элементов в диалоговом окне](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871792/tinymce-api-v4-windowmanager-open-what-widgets-can-i-configure-for-the-body-op)
3. Скачайте версию TinyMCE для разработчиков и почитайте исходный код стандартных плагинов (ссылка на официальном сайте).

Код плагина (файл plugin.min.js, который должен лежать в папке /plugins/spoiler. Также если у вас файл редактора tinymce.js, а не tinymce.min.js, то и файл должен называться plugin.js). Он достаточно прост и в нем комментарии.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('spoiler', function (editor, url) {
    // Add a button that opens a window
    editor.addButton('spoiler', {
        text: 'Спойлер',
        tooltip: 'Добавить/Удалить спойлер',
        icon: false,
        stateSelector: '.spoiler', // чтобы выделять кнопку, когда курсор на спойлере
        onclick: function () {
            var node = editor.selection.getNode(); // узел на котором курсор
            var spoiler = null; // спойлер
            if (editor.dom.hasClass(node, "spoiler")) { // если сам спойлер
                spoiler = node;
            } else {
                spoiler = editor.dom.getParent(node, ".spoiler"); // или его тело или заголовок
            }
            if(spoiler) { // если найден выбранный спойлер
                editor.dom.remove(spoiler); //удалить его
                return; // закончить
            }
            // иначе диалог создания нового спойлера
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Добавить спойлер',
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                body: [
                    {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Title'},
                    {type: 'textbox', multiline: true, flex: 1, name: 'body', label: 'Body', minHeight: 300}
                ],
                onsubmit: function (e) {
                    // Insert content when the window form is submitted
                    var body = e.data.body.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
                    var txt = '<br><div class="spoiler"><div class="spoilerhead">' + e.data.title + '</div><div class="spoilerbody">' + body + '</div></div><br>';
                    editor.insertContent(txt);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Сам плагин исключительно работает с html-разметкой. Вставляет он следующее

```
<br>
<div class="spoiler">
<div class="spoilerhead">Заголовок спойлера</div>
<div class="spoilerbody">Тело спойлера</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Стили spoiler'а подключаются при инициализации редактора. Я приведу избыточный код инициализации с обработчиками некоторых событий - они не нужны, но в качестве образца могут кому-нибудь пригодиться.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#forTinyMCE',
    language: 'ru',
    width: 700,
    height: 100,
    resize: false,
    plugins: 'link emoticons table code image spoiler',
    menubar: "edit insert view format tools",
    toolbar1: 'fontselect fontsizeselect |  bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote ',
    toolbar2: 'code | undo redo | removeformat subscript superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
    toolbar3: 'table | bold italic underline strikethrough | link unlink | emoticons | image| spoiler',
    relative_urls: false,
    setup: function (editor) { //при установке tinyMCE
        editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) { // при вставке
            var view = document.getElementById("view"); // нашли поле отображения
            view.innerHTML = editor.getContent();  // синхронизировались
        });
        editor.on('keypress', function (e) { // при нажатии клавиши
            var view = document.getElementById("view");
            view.innerHTML = editor.getContent();
        });
    },
    content_css: ['/css/spoiler.css'] // подключаем стили для спойлера          
});
```

Главное - это написать `spoiler` в поле `plugins`, а также `spoiler` в одном из toolbar'ов, чтобы кнопка отобразилась.

Сами стили (spoiler.css):

```
/*
* Стили для спойлера
*/

.spoiler {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}

.spoilerhead {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    background: lavender;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.spoilerbody {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Оживляет спойлер следующий скрипт (файл spoiler.js, нужен jQuery).

```
/* 
 * скрипт для оживления спойлера (нужен jQuery)
 */
$(".spoilerbody").hide();
$(".spoilerhead").attr("title", "Развернуть спойлер").click(function () {
    var body = $(this).next(".spoilerbody");
    body.toggle();
    if(body.is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).attr("title", "Развернуть спойлер");
    }
    else {
         $(this).attr("title", "Свернуть спойлер");
    }
});
```

Внутри редактора спойлер всегда в развернутом состоянии (думаю можно вполне оживить его и внутри редактора, но мне это было не нужно) - в него можно потом вставлять не только текст, но и все что угодно, просто повестив предварительно курсов в нужную позицию. На каждой странице, где будет спойлер, надо подключить скрипт оживляющий его `spoiler.js` и соотвествующие стили `spoiler.css`.

Ну и пара скриншотов, как это выглядит.

[image: Диалог создания спойлера]

[image: Редактор со спойлером]